# How to reduce background sounds in Talking application?

Tags: objective-c, audio, recording

I'm making a talking application like Talking Tom. I have managed to write all the code, but the background noises are pretty prominent.
I think it's something to do with the settings because I have just copied them from a recording example I found online :/

The current settings are as follows:

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,     
[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMedium], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];
```

If possible, can anyone please give me some hints as to how these settings work.